# Dynamically Getting ID of datalist options

Tags: php, jquery

As I am new to [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)/[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). I wrote code in which a `datalist` and its options are created dynamically using [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [html](/questions/tagged/html). I want to redirect when an option is clicked and I am lucky on it when I select I got redirected using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)/[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), but my problem is, that I want to get the unique id of selected option which is in my [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)-database. I am able to redirect on single id, but Iam not able to redirect dynamically.

Here is my [php](/questions/tagged/php)/[html](/questions/tagged/html) code:

```
<label for="">Students ID</label>   
<input list="lst" id="name" autocomplete="off" value="<?=@$fetch_fee['students_id']?>" name="students_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Student ID" required>
    <datalist id="lst">
        <?php 
        $q = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM students");
        while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)): ?>
            <option value="<?=$r['students_id']?>">
                <?= $r['students_name'] ?> (<?= strtoupper($r['class']) ?>)
            </option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

And this is my [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)/[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) code:

```
$("#name").on('input', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if ($('#lst').find('option').filter(function(){
            return this.value.toUpperCase() === val.toUpperCase();        
        }).length) {

        //send ajax request
        var id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
        window.location.href = "admin_panel.phpnaav=fee&collect_fee=89";
    }
});
```

I only redirect on **id 89**, but I want to redirect dynamically to the option's id, which is selected. Any help is higly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 window.location.href = "admin_panel.phpnaav=fee&collect_fee=89";
```

to

`window.location.href = "admin_panel.phpnaav=fee&collect_fee="+id`; Hope it works !

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but my problem is not solved I got this admin_panel.php?naav=fee&collect_fee=undefined